# ruby NET::IMAP reading body text

Tags: ruby, email, imap

I need to read the body of each email to find a specific number.

my code:

```
imap.search(["ON","20-Jan-2021"]).each do |message_id|
        body = imap.fetch(message_id, "BODY[]")[0].attr["BODY[]"]
        mail = Mail.new(body)
        pp mail.body
end
```

the result is something like

```
"L0Rlc3RbOCAwIFIvRml0SCA4MzJdL1BhcmVudCAxNiAwIFIvVGl0bGUoKT4+CmVuZG9iagoxOCAw\r\n" +
  "IG9iajw8L1R5cGUvQ2F0YWxvZy9QYWdlcyAxMyAwIFIvT3V0bGluZXMgMTYgMCBSPj4KZW5kb2Jq\r\n" +
  "CjE5IDAgb2JqPDwvQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlKEQ6MjAyMTAxMjAxMDQ2NDUrMDInMDAnKS9Qcm9kdWNl\r\n" +
```

I have tried to use:

```
mail.body.decoded # same result like above.
mail.text_part.decoded # error: undefined method `decoded' for nil:NilClass
mail.text_part.body.to_s # error: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the contents of the body for the Content-Transfer-Encoding, which is more than likely base64. Ruby provides a base64 module which makes it easy to decode:

```
require "base64"

# IMAP authentication and whatnot

imap.search(["ON","20-Jan-2021"]).each do |message_id|
  body = imap.fetch(message_id, "BODY[]")[0].attr["BODY[]"]
  body = Base64.decode64(body)
  mail = Mail.new(body)
  pp mail.body
end
```

FWIW, your provided text yields

```
/Dest[8 0 R/FitH 832]/Parent 16 0 R/Title()>>
endobj
18 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 13 0 R/Outlines 16 0 R>>
endobj
19 0 obj<</CreationDate(D:20210120104645+02'00')/Produce
```

when decoded from base64.